# CUDA Parallel Nsight local debugging on a GTX 590

Tags: c, debugging, windows-7, cuda, parallel-processing

Is it possible to do local debugging using Parallel Nsight on a GTX590 on Windows 7? I understand that to do local debugging you require two GPUs. The 590 has two GPUs but I cannot get this to work. I get the error message:

> Parallel Nsight Debug
> Local debugging failed. Nsight is incompatible with WPF acceleration. Please see documentation about WPF acceleration. Run the DisableWpfHardwareAcceleration.reg in your Nsight installation.

I have looked at the documentation about WPF acceleration and used the file "DisableWpfHardwareAcceleration.reg" to disable wpf acceleration - I've checked using regedit and REG_DWORD is definitely set to 1, showing that hardware acceleration has been successfully disabled. I have also set "WDDM TDR enabled" to "False" in the Nsight Monitor Options.

I have disabled SLI mode through the NVIDIA control panel by selecting 'Disable multi-GPU mode' in the 'Set multi-GPU and PhysX configuration' tab.

Using the code:

```
int devCount; 
cudaGetDeviceCount(&devCount); 
printf("CUDA Device Query...\n"); 
printf("There are %d CUDA devices.\n", devCount);
```

Outputs the message

> CUDA Device Query...
>
> There are 2 CUDA devices.

This indicates that the two GPUs in the GTX590 are viewed as two separate CUDA devices.

Despite all of this I am still getting the above error.

Comment: I am not sure if this might cause the problem, but is your card in SLI mode? Could you try disabling it and see if it makes any difference? Just a guess.

Comment: How many monitors are attached to the card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you disable WP acceleration, did you restart your system or the Nsight monitor or restart all applications that are using WPF hardware acceleration?

If one or more applications is running with WPF hardware acceleration and you run the .reg file, you could still have issues until those applications are restarted.

After disabling TDR timeout, you also need to restart your computer for that to take effect.

Also did you disable SLI on the GTX 590? If not, you can't do local debugging on it. Please also ensure that the GPU that you're debugging on does not have any output display attached to it.

The GTX 590 is based on the GF110 architecture. It should work fine with Nsight 2.0 + 270.81 driver or 275.33 driver.

Comment: How do I disable SLI mode? In the NVIDIA Control Panel I cannot find this setting anywhere. However there is a "Multi-GPU configuration" setting which I have disabled. Is this the same as disabling SLI mode?

Comment: Yes. That is the one. After which you might want to run the deviceQuery sample app from the CUDA SDK to verify that you can indeed see two separate physical devices on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that two separate CUDA devices are visible - see my edited question.

Comment: Which OS are you using by the way? Did you turn off Aero on your system?

Also, did you restart your system after running the DisableWpfHardwareAcceleration.reg file and disabling TDR?

Comment: Setting "Override local debugging checks" to "true" in the NVIDIA Parallel Nsight Options has solved this issue. First I used `cudaSetDevice(1);` so that my application was using device 1, as my monitor uses device 0. I guess that the checks that are performed before the debugging starts viewed the GTX590 as a single device that was attached to my monitor, even though it was only device 0 being used for the monitor. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try running DisableWpfHardwareAcceleration.reg again. If the registry value in question isn't a REG_DWORD set to 1, you'll get that error. Alternately, you could [set the value yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx#disablehardwareacceleration) using regedit.

BTW, the GTX 590 is not on the [supported GPUs list](http://developer.nvidia.com/parallel-nsight-supported-gpus) for the product.

Comment: I've checked using regedit and REG_DWORD is definitely set to 1.